# Keras(TensorFlow backend) multi-gpu model(4gpus) is failing when using Masking on input of LSTM network

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer, tf.keras, multi-gpu

Masking the input layer in LSTM and trying to run on multi-GPU-model with fi_genrator of Keras using TensorFlow background is throwing errors.

created a fit_generator for an LSTM, and code runs on multi-gpu-model (i see all gpu's being used on watch -n0.5 nvidia-smi) successfully. since my code has 8 timestamps and not all timestamps are available always. So, I want to use masking for the input. however, when I mask the input and run the code gives me errors.

```
class quickdrawSequence(Sequence):

def __init__(self, batch_size=128,shuffle=True,total_combinations = total_combinations,listFils=listFiles):
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.shuffle = shuffle
    self.total_combinations = total_combinations
    self.listFiles=listFils
    self.on_epoch_end()

def on_epoch_end(self):
  #'Updates indexes after each epoch'
  if self.shuffle == True:            
    np.random.shuffle(self.listFiles)    

def __len__(self):
    # number of batches for each epoch
    return self.total_combinations//self.batch_size

def __getitem__(self, idx): # this idx comes from the call of genrator by fit_generator since we inherited sequence
    #print("index from __getitem__ is : "+ str(idx))
    curnt_batchFile = listFiles[idx]
    #print(idx, curnt_batchFile)
    x,y = self.__data_generation(curnt_batchFile)
    return x, y

def __data_generation(self,curnt_batchFile):
    curnt_batchFile_x = curnt_batchFile
    curnt_batchFile_y = curnt_batchFile.replace("_x.npy","_y.npy")
    x_val = np.load(curnt_batchFile_x)
    y_val = np.load(curnt_batchFile_y)
    return x_val,y_val

training_generator = quickdrawSequence(batch_size=Batch_size,shuffle=True,total_combinations = total_combinations,listFils=listFiles)
validation_generator = quickdrawSequence(batch_size=Batch_size,shuffle=True,total_combinations = total_combinations,listFils=listFiles)


with tf.device('/cpu:0'):

    lstm_model = Sequential()

    #lstm_model.add(LSTM(units=100,input_shape=(Time_Steps,Num_Features),return_sequences=True))

    lstm_model.add(Masking(mask_value=-5,input_shape=(Time_Steps,Num_Features)))    
    lstm_model.add(LSTM(units=100,return_sequences=True))

    lstm_model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    lstm_model.add(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True))
    #lstm_model.add(BatchNormalization())
    lstm_model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    lstm_model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(25,activation='relu')))
    lstm_model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')))    

lstm_model.summary()    

parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(lstm_model, gpus=4)
parallel_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


parallel_model.fit_generator(
generator=training_generator, 
steps_per_epoch=Bbatches_afterGpuDiv,
epochs=Epochs, 
verbose=1,
validation_data=validation_generator,
validation_steps=2,
use_multiprocessing=True,
workers=8,
max_queue_size=8
)

output:

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
masking (Masking)            (None, 8, 9)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 8, 100)            44000     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 8, 100)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 8, 100)            80400     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 8, 100)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed (TimeDistri (None, 8, 25)             2525      
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_1 (TimeDist (None, 8, 1)              26        
=================================================================
Total params: 126,951
Trainable params: 126,951
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-d4fa72c44cd9> in <module>()
     40     use_multiprocessing=True,
     41     workers=8,
---> 42     max_queue_size=8
     43 )

/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.pyc in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   2175         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   2176         shuffle=shuffle,
-> 2177         initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   2178 
   2179   def evaluate_generator(self,

/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_generator.pyc in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
    174 
    175         outs = model.train_on_batch(
--> 176             x, y, sample_weight=sample_weight, class_weight=class_weight)
    177 
    178         if not isinstance(outs, list):

/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.pyc in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight)
   1938 
   1939       self._make_train_function()
-> 1940       outputs = self.train_function(ins)
   1941 
   1942     if len(outputs) == 1:

/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.pyc in __call__(self, inputs)
   2945       raise TypeError('`inputs` should be a list or tuple.')
   2946 
-> 2947     session = get_session()
   2948     feed_arrays = []
   2949     array_vals = []

/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.pyc in get_session()
    467   if not _MANUAL_VAR_INIT:
    468     with session.graph.as_default():
--> 469       _initialize_variables(session)
    470   return session
    471 

/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.pyc in _initialize_variables(session)
    729     # marked as initialized.
    730     is_initialized = session.run(
--> 731         [variables_module.is_variable_initialized(v) for v in candidate_vars])
    732     uninitialized_vars = []
    733     for flag, v in zip(is_initialized, candidate_vars):

/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    927     try:
    928       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 929                          run_metadata_ptr)
    930       if run_metadata:
    931         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1150     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1151       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1152                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1153     else:
   1154       results = []

/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1326     if handle is None:
   1327       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1328                            run_metadata)
   1329     else:
   1330       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1346           pass
   1347       message = error_interpolation.interpolate(message, self._graph)
-> 1348       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1349 
   1350   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation replica_0/sequential/lstm/transpose_1: Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
Colocation Debug Info:
Colocation group had the following types and devices: 
TensorArrayScatterV3: CPU XLA_CPU XLA_GPU 
TensorArrayReadV3: CPU XLA_CPU XLA_GPU 
Enter: GPU CPU XLA_CPU XLA_GPU 
TensorArrayV3: CPU XLA_CPU XLA_GPU 
Transpose: GPU CPU XLA_CPU XLA_GPU 

Colocation members and user-requested devices:
  replica_0/sequential/lstm/transpose_1 (Transpose) /device:GPU:0
  replica_0/sequential/lstm/TensorArray_2 (TensorArrayV3) 
  replica_0/sequential/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack_1/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3 (TensorArrayScatterV3) /device:GPU:0
  replica_0/sequential/lstm/while/TensorArrayReadV3_1/Enter (Enter) /device:GPU:0
  replica_0/sequential/lstm/while/TensorArrayReadV3_1 (TensorArrayReadV3) /device:GPU:0

Registered kernels:
  device='XLA_CPU'; Tperm in [DT_INT32, DT_INT64]; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT8, DT_COMPLEX64, DT_INT64, DT_BOOL, DT_QINT8, DT_QUINT8, DT_QINT32, DT_HALF, DT_UINT32, DT_UINT64]
  device='XLA_GPU'; Tperm in [DT_INT32, DT_INT64]; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT8, ..., DT_QINT32, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_HALF, DT_UINT32, DT_UINT64]
  device='XLA_CPU_JIT'; Tperm in [DT_INT32, DT_INT64]; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT8, DT_COMPLEX64, DT_INT64, DT_BOOL, DT_QINT8, DT_QUINT8, DT_QINT32, DT_HALF, DT_UINT32, DT_UINT64]
  device='XLA_GPU_JIT'; Tperm in [DT_INT32, DT_INT64]; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT8, ..., DT_QINT32, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_HALF, DT_UINT32, DT_UINT64]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_BOOL]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX128]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX64]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_BFLOAT16]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT8]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_UINT8]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT16]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_UINT16]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT32]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_VARIANT]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_RESOURCE]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_STRING]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_BOOL]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX128]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_BFLOAT16]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT8]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT8]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT16]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT16]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT64]

     [[node replica_0/sequential/lstm/transpose_1 (defined at <ipython-input-11-d4fa72c44cd9>:29)  = Transpose[T=DT_BOOL, Tperm=DT_INT32, _device="/device:GPU:0"](replica_0/sequential/lstm/ExpandDims, replica_0/sequential/lstm/transpose_1/perm)]]

Caused by op u'replica_0/sequential/lstm/transpose_1', defined at:
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 499, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 1017, in start
    self._run_callback(self._callbacks.popleft())
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 758, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 542, in <lambda>
    self.io_loop.add_callback(lambda : self._handle_events(self.socket, 0))
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 456, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 486, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 438, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2714, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2818, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2878, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-11-d4fa72c44cd9>", line 29, in <module>
    parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(lstm_model, gpus=4)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/multi_gpu_utils.py", line 239, in multi_gpu_model
    outputs = model(inputs)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 757, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 229, in call
    return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 845, in call
    mask=masks)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 1031, in _run_internal_graph
    output_tensors = layer.call(computed_tensor, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 2237, in call
    inputs, mask=mask, training=training, initial_state=initial_state)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 750, in call
    input_length=timesteps)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3119, in rnn
    mask = array_ops.transpose(mask, axes)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1420, in transpose
    ret = transpose_fn(a, perm, name=name)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 8927, in transpose
    "Transpose", x=x, perm=perm, name=name)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3274, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/sa/anaconda/envs/tf112_cu9_py27_pycuda_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1770, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device for operation replica_0/sequential/lstm/transpose_1: Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
Colocation Debug Info:
Colocation group had the following types and devices: 
TensorArrayScatterV3: CPU XLA_CPU XLA_GPU 
TensorArrayReadV3: CPU XLA_CPU XLA_GPU 
Enter: GPU CPU XLA_CPU XLA_GPU 
TensorArrayV3: CPU XLA_CPU XLA_GPU 
Transpose: GPU CPU XLA_CPU XLA_GPU 

Colocation members and user-requested devices:
  replica_0/sequential/lstm/transpose_1 (Transpose) /device:GPU:0
  replica_0/sequential/lstm/TensorArray_2 (TensorArrayV3) 
  replica_0/sequential/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack_1/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3 (TensorArrayScatterV3) /device:GPU:0
  replica_0/sequential/lstm/while/TensorArrayReadV3_1/Enter (Enter) /device:GPU:0
  replica_0/sequential/lstm/while/TensorArrayReadV3_1 (TensorArrayReadV3) /device:GPU:0

Registered kernels:
  device='XLA_CPU'; Tperm in [DT_INT32, DT_INT64]; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT8, DT_COMPLEX64, DT_INT64, DT_BOOL, DT_QINT8, DT_QUINT8, DT_QINT32, DT_HALF, DT_UINT32, DT_UINT64]
  device='XLA_GPU'; Tperm in [DT_INT32, DT_INT64]; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT8, ..., DT_QINT32, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_HALF, DT_UINT32, DT_UINT64]
  device='XLA_CPU_JIT'; Tperm in [DT_INT32, DT_INT64]; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT8, DT_COMPLEX64, DT_INT64, DT_BOOL, DT_QINT8, DT_QUINT8, DT_QINT32, DT_HALF, DT_UINT32, DT_UINT64]
  device='XLA_GPU_JIT'; Tperm in [DT_INT32, DT_INT64]; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT8, ..., DT_QINT32, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_HALF, DT_UINT32, DT_UINT64]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_BOOL]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX128]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX64]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_BFLOAT16]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT8]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_UINT8]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT16]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_UINT16]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT32]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_VARIANT]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_RESOURCE]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_STRING]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_BOOL]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX128]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_BFLOAT16]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT8]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT8]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT16]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT16]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT64]

     [[node replica_0/sequential/lstm/transpose_1 (defined at <ipython-input-11-d4fa72c44cd9>:29)  = Transpose[T=DT_BOOL, Tperm=DT_INT32, _device="/device:GPU:0"](replica_0/sequential/lstm/ExpandDims, replica_0/sequential/lstm/transpose_1/perm)]]
```

​

Answer (score 0):

after reading some documentation I realized what the above error is trying to tell. It says that an operation dont have a gpu implementation. if we use the soft_placement to True, such operations which don't have gpu implementation will be placed on cpu by the TF.

// Whether soft placement is allowed. If allow_soft_placement is true,
  // an op will be placed on CPU if
  //   1. there's no GPU implementation for the OP
  // or
  //   2. no GPU devices are known or registered
  // or
  //   3. need to co-locate with reftype input(s) which are from CPU.

so to the above code add, config.allow_soft_placement = True

and it works.